# Dynamically make fields in radgrid clickable

Tags: c#, dynamic, telerik, radgrid, buttonclick

Im trying to create a radgrid in which all of the values are link buttons. This is the code I have so far, it makes all of the proper values link buttons but when they are clicked on the click event does not fire, the page posts back and all of the buttons go away. I have this code in an OnitemDataBound event, which is called when the grid is loaded on page load.

```
foreach (GridColumn col in gridOver.MasterTableView.RenderColumns)
{
    if (col.UniqueName == "approved" || col.UniqueName == "submitted"
    || col.UniqueName == "rejected" || col.UniqueName == "notSub")
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        btn.ID = item.Cells[2].Text + "-" + x.ToString();
        btn.Text = dataItem[col.UniqueName].Text;
        btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        btn.Click += gridOver_Click;
        dataItem[col.UniqueName].Controls.Add(btn);
        x++;
    }
}
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(gridOver_Click);
```

and

```
btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(gridOver_Click);
```

This is what it looks like before one of the feilds is clicked: http://puu.sh/ckNyU/a2e570a8e4.png

This is what it looks like after: http://puu.sh/ckNA2/acfe7f3455.jpg

All of the fields go from being buttons to being just text again and the event does not fire.

any help would be awesome, Thanks!

Comment: Where is that code? On page load? Normally it's good to be concise with code samples on SO, but I think we might need to see more.

Comment: This code is in a OnitemDataBound event. It is called when the grid loads which occurs on page load. What other info would be required?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the LinkButtons dynamically. In ASP.NET Web Forms dynamic controls have to be re-created on all subsequent page postbacks. It is also necessary to re-create them with **the same ID's**. The ID's are important for the event  mechanism.

According to telerik [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-distinguish-differences-between-itemcreated-itemdatabound.html):

**ItemDataBound** event is fired **only** when grid binds to data.

whereas:

**ItemCreated** event is fired when grid is binding to data and when grid is binding from the ViewState, hence after **each page postback** - just before Load event occurs.

I do not know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but in order to have your link buttons present on each postback, I would suggest moving your code inside ItemCreated event:

```
protected void gridOver_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
   {
       // ... declare and init x somehow    
       foreach (GridColumn col in gridOver.MasterTableView.RenderColumns)
       {
           if (col.UniqueName == "rejected")
           {
              GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
              LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
              btn.ID = dataItem.Cells[2].Text + "-" + x.ToString();
              btn.Text = dataItem[col.UniqueName].Text;
              btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;                                    
              btn.Click += gridOver_Click;
              dataItem[col.UniqueName].Controls.Add(btn);
              x++;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Please also note that ItemCreated is fired **before** the item is data-bound. Thus no data is still in the cells' text or input controls. In ItemDataBound all is available. This might be a problem if you need to access cells' text in order to create your link buttons.